# I add OneSignal into website then I run Google PageSpped Insights, how to fix this error

Tags: onesignal

I add OneSignal into website then I run Google PageSpped Insights, how to fix this error

[image]

This is my code

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  var initConfig = {
      appId: "MYAPPID",
      autoRegister: true,
      notifyButton: {
          enable: true
      },
  };
  OneSignal.push(function () {
      OneSignal.SERVICE_WORKER_PARAM = { scope: '/' };
      OneSignal.SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = '/OneSignalSDKWorker.js';
      OneSignal.SERVICE_WORKER_UPDATER_PATH = '/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js';
      OneSignal.init(initConfig);
  });
</script>
```